# Is it possible to check if there are multiple special characters in input using regular expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use regular expression to check whether a password field contains more than two special characters in it.Is it possible to perform this check using regular expression in javascript?If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your string matches the regex: `/^(?:.*[!*$|@]){3}/` it means that there're 3 or times one of the special characters contained in the character class.

It's up to you to define tthe special characters to include in this character class

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean the special characters as `_` or any non-word character. The below regex would match the strings which has more than two (*atleast three*) special characters.

```
^.*?[\W_].*?[\W_].*[\W_].*$
```

**Example:**

```
> /^.*?[\W_].*?[\W_].*[\W_].*$/.test("foo_'bar")
false
> /^.*?[\W_].*?[\W_].*[\W_].*$/.test("foo_'ba:r")
true
> /^.*?[\W_].*?[\W_].*[\W_].*$/.test("foo_'ba:r{}{}[]")
true
```

Answer (score 0):

`x{2,}` 2 or more of x

Is probably what you are looking for

Comment: It probably is not, because this will match only if `xx` appear in that exact sequence. It would not match `x..x`.